# Is HttpUrlConnection reliable?

Tags: android, networking

I heard that it's not supported any more, but it wasn't good even a few years ago. I found a library which is perfect for me except one thing. Yeah, it uses the mentioned API. What can happen if I don't use Volley/OkHttp/Whatever instead of the deprecated HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: *I heard that it's not supported anymore*, where did you hear/read that?

Comment: I read in a blog post somewhere. It seems like it's not correct.

Comment: It looks like you want to read from trusted sources (I use the word trusted loosely here because it is the internet after all - rather use credible documentations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I heard that it's not supported anymore

`HttpURLConnection` has been supported since API Level 1. In the early Android 1.x/2.x days, it had some bugs, but those were corrected by around Android 2.3 or so.

> but it wasn't good even a few years ago

It works fine, though the API leaves a bit to be desired.

> What can happen if I don't use Volley/OkHttp/Whatever instead of the deprecated HttpUrlConnection?

`HttpURLConnection` is not deprecated. Rather, it's the official Google recommended native API. The old beta edition of Apache HttpClient that is baked into Android, however, has been discontinued, deprecated, and dropped.

In terms of what can happen, the library that you are looking to use presumably works fine.

Comment: Okay, so it's not as bad as I heard. Thanks for the clarification.